# I get an error when trying to save a sine wave audio as a .wav file

Tags: javascript, blob, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

What I'm trying to do here is play and record a simple sinusoidal wave for a few seconds and save it as a .wav file when the recording is stopped. But, I'm getting this error and the .wav file is empty.

> ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

[image]

Here is my full code.

**FULL CODE:**

```
<button onclick="play();">PLAY</button>
<button onclick="r.stop();">STOP</button>

<ul id="recordingslist"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
const context = new AudioContext();
const stream = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
let o = null,
    g = null,
    r = null;
function play(){
    o = context.createOscillator();
    g = context.createGain();
    r = new MediaRecorder(stream.stream);
    o.type = "sine";
    o.connect(g);
    o.connect(context.destination);
    o.start();
    r.start();
    r.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var au = document.createElement('audio');
        var hf = document.createElement('a');
        au.controls = true;
        au.src = url;
        hf.href = url;
        hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
        hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
        li.appendChild(au);
        li.appendChild(hf);
        document.getElementById('recordingslist').appendChild(li);
        o.stop();
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here.

---

Regarding the MediaRecorder part, the *dataavailable* event may fire at any time the browser deems necessary, it may even fire with no data at all.

If you want to record a fixed duration of time, then listen for the *stop* event to build your download link, and use the *dataavailable* one only to push the chunks of data the browser will have output during that time:

---

Regarding the AudioContext part,
you can think of the link connection as a [guitar - pedal(s) - pre-amp - ampli] setup. Each `connect` being a new wire between two nodes.
In your setup, you did create a gain node, and did connect your oscillator to it, you now need to connect your gain node (`g`) to the MediaStreamDestinationNode (`stream`) if you want to record it.  Failing to do so, nothing will get passed to the recorder since the stream-destination node will not be connected to anything.

```js
const context = new AudioContext();
const stream = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = play;

function play() {
  const o = context.createOscillator();
  const g = context.createGain();
  const r = new MediaRecorder(stream.stream);
  o.type = "sine";
  g.gain.value = 0.5;
  o.connect(g);
  // you want to connect the gainNode to the stream-dest
  g.connect(stream);
  // and to the context's dest (speakers)
  g.connect(context.destination);
  o.start(0);
  // we need an Array to store all the chunks
  const chunks = [];
  // in dataavailable we only push the new chunks
  r.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };
  // we wait until the recorder has been stopped to build the final media
  r.onstop = function(e) {
    // concatenate all the chunks in a single Blob
    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const au = document.createElement('audio');
    const hf = document.createElement('a');
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    hf.href = url;
    // setting the filename's extension won't make it a wav file
    // what you have here is an ogg-vorbis audio file.
    hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.oga';
    hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(hf);
    document.getElementById('recordingslist').appendChild(li);
    o.stop();
  };
  r.start();
  // stop the recording in 3s
  setTimeout(() => {
    r.stop();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">start</button>
<ul id="recordingslist"></ul>
```